# When installing Ubunt 12.10 my computer freezes while trying to install the OS

Tags: 12.10

it is a gateway laptop, intel celeron, and 256MB of ram,
I got this computer from my neighbor for free, and it has windows xp on it and I do not want windows, I'd rather have Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

@jacob, you need to upgrade your RAM to at least 768 MB. Please refer to this for the [complete system requirements information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_Requirements).